# Twitter cashtags access via 3rd party library?

Tags: api, twitter

I am looking for the possibility to use cashtags like $GOOGL from Twitter API.
As you know Twitter offers such access only in Enterprise plan and it's very expensive for R'n'D purposes.
That's why I've started looking for some 'aggregators' or social media analytics projects who could offer it in more attractive price. I assume that as they aggregate a lot of customers they are able to negotiate better conditions for accessing the API.

So, I'm asking you about such projects or maybe better naming keywords to search which could help me to find what I am looking for.

To be more precise I would like to have a possibility to call the API from my application.

Thanks in advance for any tips or comments.

EDIT:
I should mention that I would like to query tweet counts by using cashtags.

Answer (score 0):

The cashtag operator is now available in Essential access for v2 on the filtered stream API https://developer.twitter.com/en/blog/product-news/2022/twitter-api-v2-filtered-stream